# SSRS Burn down chart with Condition depending on current X axis value

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart, ssrs-2012

I am new with SSRS and trying to create a burn down chart with the following data.
I have a sample data table

### Task   Duration Months

TSk1       1
TSk2       2
TSk3       3

I want to plot a bar graph with duration months(monthly- M1, M2, M3)on xaxis and count of tasks that have duration greater than or equal to the Mx(Mx- is the corresponding month on the x axis)
For M1 the tasks count should be 3, M2- 2 and M3- 1, M4- 0.
How do I do this in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by creating a table that CROSS joins the Dbo.Numbers table to repeat the rows on the number of months for the task. which creates n duplicate records (n from 1,2,3 ... no of months).
Then from the data a regular Bar chart with n as month Number and Count(Task).